# Sitecore Azure deployment using Visual Studio

Tags: sitecore, azure-web-app-service, sitecore8

I am trying Sitecore deployment to Azure using Visual Studio referencing the link and instructions from
http://blog.petersondave.com/sitecore/azure/Alternate-Sitecore-8-Azure-Deployment-Options/
https://kb.sitecore.net/en/Articles/2014/07/30/16/07/983166.aspx

When i have included specifies files and folders in VS solution, build is giving error. all the controls are showing does not exists in current context in all the .cs files.

Any idea?

Comment: 8.0 latest release?  Also, I assume PaaS? There's a new kb article out, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: I have resolve those issues now its published successfully. When browsing from Azure, its throwing below error message: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Azure.Startup.Pipelines.Loader.RebuildSearchIndex, Sitecore.Azure.Startup